# How to replicate `az ad app list` using Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-python-sdk

How do I replicate `az ad app list` using the official Azure Python SDK?

The answer which I found included using [azure-graphrbac](https://pypi.org/project/azure-graphrbac/) but it's deprecated. The official docs says to use Microsoft Graph API instead, but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Update:

```
import asyncio

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = GraphServiceClient(credential)


async def main():
    result = await client.applications.get()
    return result


asyncio.run(main())
```

Here's a code which I came up with, but running this gives me an error.

```
msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error.ODataError:
        APIError
        Code: 403
        message: None
        error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='Authorization_RequestDenied', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={'date': DateTime(2023, 12, 7, 5, 41, 17, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC'))}, client_request_id='ee33797c-1ae4-4a00-99bd-5cf8ed30301b', date=None, odata_type=None, request_id='b5d36ffa-5cdc-4c7c-aaa9-9aef55bcf5ab'), message='Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', target=None)
```

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-on-premises-apps?tabs=azure-portal) article to setup an application and assigned 'Reader' role in the IAM permission.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include more details like what code you tried and where you stuck? Are you trying to run `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications` in Python?

Comment: @Sridevi Updated the question to include the code I came up with.

Comment: You need to grant `Application.Read.All` Microsoft Graph permission in your application. With `Reader` role, I too got [same error](https://i.imgur.com/w503f7c.png) as it works only under subscription level resources not tenant level.

Comment: I'm using `msgraph-sdk` package with version **1.0.0a14** in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the service principal does not have proper **permissions** or **roles** to perform the operation. Note that, **`Reader`** role works to manage only Azure resources under subscription level, not tenant level.

To **resolve** the error, you need to add  `Application.Read.All` Microsoft Graph permission in your app registration and make sure to grant **admin consent** to it like this:

[image]

In my case, I ran below modified python code and got **response** with application details successfully:

```py
import asyncio

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph import GraphServiceClient
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

tenant_id = os.getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID")
client_id = os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID")
client_secret = os.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET")

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

client = GraphServiceClient(credential)

async def main():
    result = await client.applications.get()
    applications = result.value
    for app in applications:
        print("App Name:", app.display_name)
        print("App ID:", app.app_id)
        print("--------------------------------------------------")

asyncio.run(main())
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Sridevi! This indeed fixed my problem! <3